# PHP array values issue with two if statements

Tags: php, if-statement

I am using simple php code to parse a file. There are 2 IF statements.

1. If statement is using preg_match and looks for certain pattern, there is match found
2. I put in array X
3. Now there is second If statement that is also using preg_match looking for some pattern, there is match found.
4. I print values from second If statement in table, but I also want the values found in first if statement to be printed in the table as well. However, I do not see values from array X being printed instead it I see empty line.

When I do print_r for array x within first If statement I can clearly see array has all the values not sure why it does not get printed in my table which is created once there is match found in second if statement.

Anyone has any inputs. It seems I should be doing nested if but that is not working for me.
  Data in $file is

> abc test1 for test1: xxx   test1> test3> x/y/z: x1 / y2 / z3   abc test2
>   for test2: xxx   test2> test3> x/y/z: x1 / y2 / z3   abc test3 for test3:
>   xxx   test3> x/y/z: x1 / y2 / z3

I am also uploading image how the format of the data is in file.
[fileformatofabovedata](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cK4W3.jpg)

```
   while(!feof($file))  {
  $str = fgets($file);  $array = (explode(":",$str));    if(preg_match("/x1|y2|z3/",$array[1])){
        $versions = (explode("/",$array[1])); 

      }  
     if(preg_match("/abc|:xxx|:yyy/", $array[0])) {
        $count++;   
       echo "<tr><td>Test case $count</td><td>$array[0]</td><td>$versions[0]</td><td>$versions[1]</td><td>$versions[2]</td><td>$array[1]</td></tr>";
       }

        }
```

In $versions I get 3 values I want to print them even if second IF statement finds a matching pattern. Since the second IF statement also has matching pattern array values in first IF statement are discarded. Loop continues to read the file. I have uploaded current output in jpg format.
[my current output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbdxN.jpg)
Table should have properly filled the data in row 1 as well. But it gets printed in second row instead. Basically all 3 rows should be filled with correct data.

Comment: Where is your code?

Comment: Please go read [ask], and [mcve].

Comment: @Nico Haase please see updated with code.

Comment: @mickmackusa Thanks for reply. I cannot provide much info about $str. I can say that first if statement gets the value but it does not printed in first row of table instead it skipped and gets printed on second row of my table. Basically, rows are shifted by 1 i.e. 1st  row matched in very first if statement gets printed in second row and so on. I am wondering if both if statements are true then appropriate value should be printed in table, not sure why it gets printed in second row.

Comment: Also first if statement is typo it should be like x1|y2|z3

Comment: @mickmackusa here is the $str basically it has data from file `abc test1 for test1: xxx
test1> test3> x/y/z: x1 / y2 / z3
abc test2 for test2: xxx
test2> test3> x/y/z: x1 / y2 / z3
abc test3 for test3: xxx
test3> x/y/z: x1 / y2 / z3`

Comment: @mickmackusa I have uploaded image of sample data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you pull the entire contents of your input file into a string (using `file_get_contents`) rather than work line-by-line because your targeted data arrives in pairs of lines.

My supplied pattern uses some very general negated character classes and techniques to isolate the substrings in your sample data.  If this pattern does not work for your actual project, you will need to provide a more realistic set of input data.

[Pattern Demo](https://regex101.com/r/7r0NvS/1)  <-- this provides the pattern breakdown

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/tRoQp))

```
$contents = file_get_contents($file);    
if (!preg_match_all('~^([^:>]+):\s(\S+)[^:]+:\s(\S+)\s/\s(\S+)\s/\s(\S+)\s*$~m', $contents, $matches, PREG_SET_ORDER)) {
    echo "Pattern Failed";
} else {
    echo "<table>";
        foreach ($matches as $i => $data) {
            echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>Test case " , ++$i , "</td>";
                echo "<td>{$data[1]}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$data[3]}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$data[4]}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$data[5]}</td>";
                echo "<td>{$data[2]}</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    echo "</table>";
}
```

Output:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Test case 1</td>
        <td>abc test1 for test1</td>
        <td>x1</td>
        <td>y2</td>
        <td>z3</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test case 2</td>
        <td>abc test2 for test2</td>
        <td>x1</td>
        <td>y2</td>
        <td>z3</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Test case 3</td>
        <td>abc test3 for test3</td>
        <td>x1</td>
        <td>y2</td>
        <td>z3</td>
        <td>xxx</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for tip of using file_contents, I did not think of it.  I have got the table working with minor regex changes to match my needs, I was initially trying to get into array but some how made it too complicated. I just need to add table headings and also reset the $i after 5 or 6 counts.

Comment: Those seem like simple adjustments.  If you would like a hand with the mopping up, I won't be cranky about supporting small question extensions.  Glad to help.